# SQL: find if there are 10 consecutive dates that have a certain value in another column in redshift

Tags: sql, logic, amazon-redshift

is there a way in redshift SQL to tell if there is a 10 consecutive days stretch where Rates='Y'?. In the example below the answer would be No.

Table name: rates

```
Dates        Rates
1/1/2021       Y
1/2/2021       Y
1/3/2021       Y
1/4/2021       N
1/5/2021       N
1/6/2021       N
1/7/2021       Y
1/8/2021       Y
1/9/2021       Y
1/10/2021      Y
1/11/2021      Y
1/12/2021      Y
1/13/2021      Y
```

Comment: you can use a series of 9 JOINs (FROM tab t1 JOIN tab t2 on t2.dates = t1.dates - 1) JOIN tab t3 ON t3.dates = t2.dates - 1 JOIN tab t4 ON <you get the idea>).  Or you could use a series of nine subselects.

Comment: I'm new to sql. can you please elaborate? I don't think I get it.

Comment: Make it 3, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `sum()` as a window function and some aggregation.  Assuming that you have one row per day (i.e. you want 10 *rows*).  You can get all the rows that have 10 in a row using:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(date, 9) over (partition by rates order by date) as prev_date_9
      from t
     ) t
where prev_date_9 = date - interval '9 day' and
      rates = 'Y';
```

One way to get a flag is to use aggregation:

```
select (case when count(*) = 0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end)
from (select t.*, lag(date, 9) over (partition by rates order by date) as prev_date_9
      from t
     ) t
where prev_date_9 = date - interval '9 day' and
      rates = 'Y';
```

This assumes that your data has exactly one row per day, which is how the data in your question is structured.

Comment: Intriguing.  What RDBMS are you implementing here?  I've not seen this "interval '9 day'" before; want to review this cool trick.  If it does what I think it might, then how are you ensuring that there are no gaps in the 10-day range?

Comment: @Dennis . . . `interval` is part of standard SQL.  Postgres requires the entire interval to be a string.

Comment: Just updated my comment @Gordon.  So there's nothing here to ensure there's no gap in the 10-day period, right?

Comment: The great thing about standards: There are so many from which to choose.  :)  interval is not present in IBM DB2, nor in Oracle.  They have their ways, but they look different from this.

Comment: @Dennis .  . Oracle does support `interval` (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions009.htm#SQLRF52064).  But I liken SQL to English . . . some of the regional versions are mutually incomprehensible ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, using the JOIN concept I mentioned above:

```
SELECT t1.dates AS to_date, ta.dates AS from_date
FROM   my_table t1
JOIN   my_table t2 on t2.dates = (t1.dates - 1) AND t2.rates = t1.rates
JOIN   my_table t3 on t3.dates = (t2.dates - 1) AND t3.rates = t1.rates
JOIN   my_table t4 on t4.dates = (t3.dates - 1) and t4.rates = t1.rates
JOIN   my_table t5 on t5.dates = (t4.dates - 1) AND t5.rates = t1.rates
JOIN   my_table t6 on t6.dates = (t5.dates - 1) AND t6.rates = t1.rates
JOIN   my_table t7 on t7.dates = (t6.dates - 1) AND t7.rates = t1.rates
JOIN   my_table t8 on t8.dates = (t7.dates - 1) AND t8.rates = t1.rates
JOIN   my_table t9 on t9.dates = (t8.dates - 1) AND t9.rates = t1.rates
JOIN   my_table ta on ta.dates = (t9.dates - 1) AND ta.rates = t1.rates
WHERE  t1.rates = 'Y'
```

Another approach that might read more to your liking (JOIN confuses some people) :

```
SELECT t1.dates as to_date, t1-dates - 9 AS from_date
FROM   my_table t1
WHERE  t1.rates = 'Y'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table t2 WHERE t2.dates = t1.dates - 1 AND t2.rates = t1.rates)
AND EXISTS (select 1 FROM ... (yes, you would have to type in all the rest...  I'm lazy.)
```

I know of no way to ensure there is no gap, other than hand-coding, as you've seen here.

Note also that you did not specify your RDBMS so I've given you a DB2-ish solution.  You may have to adjust the (dates - 1) syntax for your RDBMS.

Have fun.